# Writing XPath for selecting the description

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I want to extract the description from the HTML Pages.

My `div` id is contains below data:

```
  <div class="container page_op-detail">
 <form id="j_id0:OpenPositionTemplate:j_id21" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/careers/OpenPosDetail?id=a0m80000002zvKeAAI" method="post" name="j_id0:OpenPositionTemplate:j_id21">
 <span id="ajax-view-state-page-container" style="display: none">
 <p> Solving the world’s hardest problems is no easy task. Our engineers often find themselves in the midst of combat zones, disaster relief efforts or even worse, boardrooms. AP Specialists ensure that our engineers have every tool they need to crack some of the most challenging and puzzling problems on the planet. We do this by managing numerous relationships with vendors across the country and around the globe that can provide our engineers with everything they need to make the world a safer place. As our company continues to grow, we are constantly thinking about how to improve and automate processes so we can continue providing amazing outcomes in even more places across the world.</p>
 <p>
    <strong>Responsibilities</strong>
  </p>
  <ul>
     <li> Ownership and oversight of full-cycle accounts payable responsibilities including but not limited to, invoice processing, maintaining vendor records, running payment reports according to payment schedules, reconciling vendor statements)</li>
     <li> Identify and implement process improvements and automation in appropriate areas throughout the AP cycle</li>
     <li> Provide excellent customer service to vendors and employees by researching and resolving inquiries in a timely manner</li>
     <li> Assist with month-end activities, accruals, reconciliation, preparing 1099s, and audit support</li>
   <li> Assist with ad-hoc requests</li>
  </ul>
 <p>
    <strong>Qualifications</strong>
 </p>
  <ul>
     <li> AA/AS degree or equivalent experience in accounting</li>
     <li> Three years or more of related experience</li>
     <li> Full cycle accounts payable knowledge</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="type-centered">
       Data is more organised...!!!
   </p>
  <p class="type-centered apply-button">
  </div>
```

Here I need only data `<p>` tags. I don't want data which contains Responsibilities and Qualifications from

```
<p>Responsibliites</p><ul> ... </ul>
<p>Qualifications</p><ul> .. </ul>
```

This is not necessary and exclude it from XPATH.

I am using below code:

```
sel.xpath(
        'description',
        '//div[@class="container page_op-detail"][not(descendant-or-self::p/strong[contains(text(), "Qualifications")]/../ul[1])]'
    ).extract()
```

This is not working. Please help me to create XPath which items can exclude it. How can I write the XPATH for this type of queries?

Expected OUTPUT:

```
<div class="container page_op-detail">
 <form id="j_id0:OpenPositionTemplate:j_id21" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/careers/OpenPosDetail?id=a0m80000002zvKeAAI" method="post" name="j_id0:OpenPositionTemplate:j_id21">
 <span id="ajax-view-state-page-container" style="display: none">
 <p> Solving the world’s hardest problems is no easy task. Our engineers often find themselves in the midst of combat zones, disaster relief efforts or even worse, boardrooms. AP Specialists ensure that our engineers have every tool they need to crack some of the most challenging and puzzling problems on the planet. We do this by managing numerous relationships with vendors across the country and around the globe that can provide our engineers with everything they need to make the world a safer place. As our company continues to grow, we are constantly thinking about how to improve and automate processes so we can continue providing amazing outcomes in even more places across the world.</p>

  <p class="type-centered">
       Data is more organised...!!!
   </p>
  <p class="type-centered apply-button">
  </div>
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Expected OUTPUT should be:     <div class="container page_op-detail">
 <form id="j_id0:OpenPositionTemplate:j_id21" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"         action="/careers/OpenPosDetail?id=a0m80000002zvKeAAI" method="post" name="j_id0:OpenPositionTemplate:j_id21">
 <span id="ajax-view-state-page-container" style="display: none">
 <p> Solving the world’s hardest problems is no easy task. Our engineers often find ....... </p>
  <p class="type-centered">
       Data is more organised...!!!
   </p>
  <p class="type-centered apply-button">
  </div>

Comment: exclude the <p><strong>Responsiblities</strong></p><ul>...</ul>   and <p><strong>Qualifications</strong></p><ul>...</ul>           So that i want remove <p> and <ul> lists

Comment: It is better to include your expected output in your question rather than in comments, for readability purposes.

Comment: The `form` and `span` and the last `p` end tags are missing. Your input is malformed.

Comment: For which library? You should be using a jQuery-style library for selecting html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that `form` and `span` tags are empty elements, you can try this xpath:

```
/div[@class='container page_op-detail']/*[not(self::p[normalize-space(.)='Responsibilities']) 
                                        and not(self::ul[preceding-sibling::p[normalize-space(.)='Responsibilities']])
                                        and not(self::ul[preceding-sibling::p[normalize-space(.)='Qualifications']])
                                        and not(self::p[normalize-space(.)='Qualifications'])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but still not working.. its showing complete empty list..  any alternate solution ?

Comment: I have assumed that `form` and `span` tags are empty elements. Please fix your input. Are they ancestors of `p`s and `ul`s?

Comment: i just used like this.    "//div[@class='container page_op-detail']/*[not(self::p[normalize-space(.)='Responsibilities'])  and not(self::ul) and not(self::p[normalize-space(.)='Qualifications']) and not(self::ul)]"

Comment: I have tested that using xpathtester.com. Please see this (http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8d692a09ac707d9c6891af086c472bfe)

Comment: Please see this url : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8d692a09ac707d9c6891af086c472bfe

Comment: i added <p>Preferred </p><ul>..</ul>. currently this will removing.. but i want to keep as it is with <p> and <ul> tags data.  How can i achieve this one ?

Comment: <p>Preferred</p> <ul> ...</ul>  here <ul> tag contents are removed.. i need keep this as it is.. your edited answer is works almost ok..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your html code miss several closing tags, including `</form>, </p>, </span>` etc.  I assume the following html codes are the correct version:

```
<div class="container page_op-detail">
<form id="j_id0:OpenPositionTemplate:j_id21" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"         action="/careers/OpenPosDetail?id=a0m80000002zvKeAAI" method="post" name="j_id0:OpenPositionTemplate:j_id21"></form>
<span id="ajax-view-state-page-container" style="display: none"></span>
<p> Solving the world’s hardest problems ... </p>
<p>
<strong>Responsibilities</strong>
</p>
<ul>
 <li> Ownership and oversight of full-cycle .....</li>
 <li> Identify and implement process improvements ...</li>
 <li> Provide excellent customer service to vendors ... </li>
 <li> Assist with month-end activities, accruals, ...</li>
<li> Assist with ad-hoc requests</li>
</ul>
<p>
<strong>Qualifications</strong>
</p>
<ul>
 <li> AA/AS degree or equivalent experience in accounting</li>
 <li> Three years or more of related experience</li>
 <li> Full cycle accounts payable knowledge</li>
</ul>
<p class="type-centered">
   Data is more organised...!!!
</p>
<p class="type-centered apply-button"></p>
</div>
```

The first `<p>` tag can be extracted by using:

```
//div[@class="container page_op-detail"]/p[1]/text()
```

The next `<p>` tag you need can be extracted by:

```
//div[@class="container page_op-detail"]/p[@class="type-centered"]/text()
```

Then you can use **itemloader** to append the two extractions into the same item 'description', as shown by  [scrapy example here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) or as below:

```
rom scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import Product

def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
    l.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="product_name"]')       
    l.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="product_title"]')  //note: item 'name' are used twice.
    return l.load_item()
```